# how to open sidenav when mouse goes out of screen in fullscreen mode of video in html5?

Tags: html, video, hover, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

I want to call function which opens sidenav in webpage. But I want to do it when my mouse cursor goes out of the screen in full =screen mode of video in HTML5. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$('video#my-video').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

    // Now add mouse detection and display nav if mouse is where you want it   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register an event for that so I dont think its possible.Also, if you are in fullscreen mode, how will you go out of the screen. You can only move it to a corner and not out of the screen.

Comment: out of the screen means at the edge of the screen.